# How Grid.ColumnDefinition works in c#,xaml windows 8

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

I am new to windows 8 xaml development.
See the following code

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="35*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="65*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

I want to understand that how the space will be divided according to the Columdefinitions.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if this is what you're looking for:

Because you have used the star as unit, the first column will get 35 percent of the available size. The second column will get 65.

If you dont provide the star, the first column will be 35 DIPs (Device Independent pixels) wide, the second 65 DIPs.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest explaination for grid row/column height/width is [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html#rowscols)

The size can be specified as an absolute amount of logical units, as a percentage value or automatically.

> Fixed  Fixed size of logical units (1/96 inch)
>
> Auto   Takes as much space as needed by the contained control
>
> Star (*) Takes as much space as available (after filling all auto and
>   fixed sized columns), proportionally divided over all star-sized
>   columns. So 3*/5* means the same as 30*/50*. Remember that star-sizing
>   does not work if the grid size is calculated based on its content.